# ¿porque dice error en el query?

Tags: php, mysql

la Verdad e revisado de pie a Cabeza y supuestamente yo no le veo error, pero me dice error y no me inserta en la base de datos.

```
<?php
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "antetodopopayan");

if(!$conexion){
    echo "error";
}else{
    echo "yes";
}

    $titulo= $_POST["titulo"];
    $subtitulo= $_POST["Stitulo"];
    $articulo= $_POST["articulo"];
    $fotos= $_POST["img"];
    $autor= $_POST["autor"];

$consulta="INSERT INTO noticias (id, titulo_noticia, subtitulo_noticias, descripcion_noticia, autor_noticia, fotos_noticia, fecha) VALUES 
(null,'$titulo','$subtitulo','$articulo','$autor','$fotos', NOW())";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("error en el query");


mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: Lanzale un echo $consulta para que veas como te estan llegando las variables

Comment: Intenta imprimir el error, poniéndolo así: `or die ( "error en el query".mysqli_error($conexion) )`  ... y no entiendo por qué no pones todo lo relativo a la inserción dentro del `else` (donde dice `echo "yes"`) es ahí donde debería ir.

Comment: por que invocas a la columna `id` de tu tabla? esta no es PK? si es así no tienes por que colocarla

Comment: @shadow pero si la coloca no es motivo de error, se puede en efecto usar una PK en una consulta si se le asigna `null` como valor, tal y como el OP está haciendo. Aunque como dices, no es necesario hacerlo, pero no significa que sea inválido o erróneo.

Comment: No te suelta ningún mensaje de error?
 Has probado a mirar el log de errores?? Asegurate también de que los campos son los correctos. Por ejemplo "subtitulo_noticias" es el único que veo en que "noticia" está en plural.